# Center of a group contains a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying to an exam in abstract algebra, and I'm stuck on the following question. I will appreciate any guidance for this one.

Let $G=H\times K$ be a Group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of G.

Assume that $N\cap K=\{1\}$ and $N\cap H=\{1\}$.

Prove that $N\subseteq Z(G)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N$ is not in the center, then there exists $(h, k) \in G$ and $(x, y) \in N$ such that $(hxh^{-1},kyk^{-1})\in N$ and either $hxh^{-1}\neq x$ or $kyk^{-1}\neq y$. Assume without loss of generality that the former is true and $k$ is the identity. Thus $(x, y), (hxh^{-1},y)\in N$, hence $(x, y) (hxh^{-1},y)^{-1}=(xhx^{-1}h^{-1},1)\in N$. Since the commutator is nontrivial, $N$ intersects nontrivially with $H$.